# Accessing variables of a struct from another nested structs variable in Go

Tags: go

Given are 2 structs I wrote.

```
type DNSPacket struct {
    header      DNSHeader.DNSHeader
    questions   []DNSQuestion.DNSQuestion
    answers     []DNSRecord.DNSRecord
    authorities []DNSRecord.DNSRecord
    resources   []DNSRecord.DNSRecord
}
```

```
type DNSHeader struct {
    id uint16 //16bits

    recursion_desired    bool  // 1 bit
    truncated_message    bool  // 1 bit
    authoritative_answer bool  // 1 bit
    opcode               uint8 // 4 bits
    response             bool  // 1 bit

    rescode             ResultCode // 4 bits
    checking_disabled   bool       // 1 bit
    authed_data         bool       // 1 bit
    z                   bool       // 1 bit
    recursion_available bool       // 1 bit

    questions             uint16 // 16 bits
    answers               uint16 // 16 bits
    authoritative_entries uint16 // 16 bits
    resource_entries      uint16 // 16 bits
} // total 96 bits
```

Now, when I call `results.header.questions` where results is a type DNSPacket variable I get a `[go] result.header.questions undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method questions)` error.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: Not related to the issue but I would suggest you read this https://blog.golang.org/package-names, in case you care about such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues here:

1. The fields of both your structs are not exported outside the package that contains them, because they begin with a lowercase letter. If you want to access fields outside of the package, they have to start with an uppercase letter.
2. Name your packages in lowercase, like `dnsheader`, not `DNSHeader`.

Read the spec on [exported names](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) and Effective Go on [package names](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names)

Comment: I understood why 1.But why 2?

Comment: @SumukhaPk: it's a convention. Breaking it makes your code immediately feel "strange" and unfamiliar